# Select a group from Grouping Column ag-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm wondering if there's a way to select the one group from row in ag-grid.

I use [Column Group](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping-headers/) tool and i have a lot of groups in a row which are different only by index (`column-index`)

There are situations then i need to use only a part of the row (one group): pinning, drag/drop.

How can i get only one group from a row?
[image]